# Calculating performance metrics using trace.json for simulation in UnetStack3

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I am working on the tool to calculate different `performance metrics` (like average end-to-end delay, throughput, packet delivery ratio, etc.) for the simulation of underwater networks in UnetStack3. I have done an implementation in python that parses the `trace.json` and calculates end-to-end delay. However, it works only for topology with one-hop communication, as I have considered the MessageID of the events. Further, I analyzed the implementation of the `VizTrace tool` in Julia and tried to extend the implementation. However, I am unable to figure out how to co-relate events that occur in different nodes for calculating performance measures in a multi-hop topology. Please let me know what approach I should follow with Python and with the vizTrace.

Answer (score 0):

Every event entry in the `trace.json` file contains a few useful pieces of information to help you associate events across nodes:

- `component`: name and class of the agent, along with the node on which it is running
- `threadID`: unique identifier within a node that associates related events together.
- `stimulus`: contains `messageID` of the message that caused this event.
- `response`: contains `messageID` of the message that was sent in response to this event.

For more details, see https://blog.unetstack.net/whats-new-in-UnetStack-3.3

Tracing an event through the agents in the node simply involves collating the events with the same `threadID`. In order to trace an event across nodes, you need to look at the `messageID` of the `response` messages, and find the equivalent `stimulus` message (same `messageID`) on the next node. Then you do the same from that node to the following one, until you reach the destination.

If you are using the `HalfDuplexModem` simulation model, then these messages that go across nodes (and hence across `threadID`s) will be the `HalfDuplexModem$TX` messages. Example: https://blog.unetstack.net/assets/img/mermaid-diagram-20210408195013.svg